# Want to delete rows from a table using another company code table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables Raw_data and CoCode. I want a access query to delete all rows from Raw_data table which does not have company codes in CoCode table.

Comment: . . . Provide sample data, desired results, and your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: What did do you try so far? what are you using access or sql? if sql what sql version are you using?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I used the below: the column with the code are named Companycode in Raw_data and company_codes in CoCode: DELETE FROM Raw_data WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * CoCode WHERE CoCode.company_codes = Raw_data.Companycode)

Comment: @Yan I am using access 2013.

I used the below: the column with the code are named Companycode in Raw_data and company_codes in CoCode: DELETE FROM Raw_data WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * CoCode WHERE CoCode.company_codes = Raw_data.Companycode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. Assuming the column with the code are named `code` in `Raw_data` and `id` in `CoCode`:

```
DELETE FROM Raw_data
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     CoCode
                                     WHERE CoCode.id = Raw_data.code)
```

Comment: I used the below: the column with the code are named Companycode in Raw_data and company_codes in CoCode:


DELETE FROM Raw_data
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     CoCode
                                     WHERE CoCode.company_codes = Raw_data.Companycode)